# Magento 2.3.4 images 404 after caching. Reappear after flush catalog images

Tags: cache, data-migration, media-images, magento2.4.3

I have migrated from Magento 1. The migration seemed to go fine. Orders and products are in.

I have not installed any themes as I wanted to get it running on Luna before changing anything.

So the product images show once if I 'Flush Images Cache' in the admin. They show once and then if the page is refreshed then they are showing a 404.

This is the same for the product image.

I have tried to reindex, deploy, upgrade and resize images. They seem to run successfully but images do not show until a images flush is done.

Images are assigned to the site.

There is also no logo image and the thumbnails do not show in the backend. uploaded images are showing as 404.

I have been through dozens of suggestions and am hitting a blank.

I have checked permissions several times and cannot see anything wrong.
Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should be related to webserver(nginx/apache) rule for processing media.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for an answer. I host another magento site on the server and that has no problems.